# References for properties of a $K3$ surface

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, k3-surfaces

I have read that the surface $K3$ in $\mathbb{CP}^3$ defined by the equation $x^4+y^4+z^4+w^4=0$ is a spin manifold whose $\hat{A}$-genus is non-vanishing. However, not knowing algebraic geometry, I am not sure where to look in order to better understand some basic properties of this surface and was wondering whether anyone could point me to some specific references (notes, book chapters) that might address the following.

1. Why is $K3$ a smooth manifold?
2. Does $K3$ separate $\mathbb{CP}^3$ into two parts - that is, whether there exist two compact submanifolds $A$ and $B$ with common boundary $K3$ such that $A\cup B=\mathbb{CP}^3$?

Many thanks!

**Edit:** As pointed in the comments, the answer to question 2 is no because of dimensional considerations. So I would like to ask the following modified question:

3. Does there exist a (5-dimensional) real submanifold $N$ of $\mathbb{CP}^3$ that is spin such that we can find compact submanifolds $A$ and $B$ of $N$ with common boundary $K3$, with $A\cup B=N$?

Comment: What is your definition of $K3$? And think about the real dimension for question 2.

Comment: Your variety is a smooth manifold by, e.g., the Jacobean criterion. As to the other point, I'm no topologist, but certainly the complement is connected, since the manifold only has four real dimensions. Saint-Donat's "Projective Models of K3 Surfaces" is a good reference for K3 surfaces in general.

Comment: Ah yes you're right about question 2. Is the equation $x^4+y^4+z^4+w^4=0$ not unambiguous?

Comment: @ougoah what you mean by unambiguous? another good reference is huybrechts' book on K3 surfaces

Comment: Be careful. Your surface is usually referred to as the "Fermat quartic surface" and it is an example of a type of surfaces which are called "K3 surfaces". Calling it "$K3$" and not $S$ or $X$, for instance, is a bit misleading.